# What's the easiest way to run x86_64 applications on aarch (Arm)?

Tags: arch-linux, macintosh, x86, emulation, arm64

I'm currently running the Asahi (Linux on the M1 Macbook pro) beta with Arch Linux, but would like to run some x86/x86_64 binaries, and am wondering the best way to do that.

I saw [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577953/is-it-possible-to-run-x86-executable-on-arm) thread discussing how to do it on Debian, but couldn't get any success. Here are some various things I've tried:

- Installing [qemu](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/QEMU) for emulation (package can't satisfy dependencies)
- Installing [FEX-Emu](https://github.com/FEX-Emu/FEX) (after I installed it from the AUR, I had no `fex` command)
- Installing [Bochs](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/bochs/) from the Community repository, but it gives `error: target not found: bochs`
- Installing [box86](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/box86) from the AUR, but it fails to build since it doesn't seem compatible with aarch hosts

Anyone have any suggestions? I'm just looking for what's easiest to get up and running.

Comment: I’m curious about your results with Bochs; it works fine for me on Aarch64 (but I haven’t tried on a Mac).

Comment: Updated OP with response; perhaps I'm missing Community repo? `sudo pacman -S bochs` gives `error: target not found: bochs`